# How to send DTO list using Retrofit2 in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm studying Android programming using Kotlin. I am currently in the process of communicating with the server using Retrofit2. One of the data that needs to be passed to the server side is a list with one set of text and one picture. The content type is 'multipart/form-data' when I send it.

If it is expressed as a data class, it is as follows.

```
data class DataItem(
    val text: String,
    val image: File
)
```

What I want to send is a list of this data class object.
If I express what I want to do as Retrofit service definition in meaning, it's as follows.

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/post")
    fun addPost(
        @Part dataList: List<DataItem>   // But it didn't work
    ): Call<PostResponse>
```

I tried changing the data class in the following way, but it didn't work out either.

```
data class DataItem(
    val text: RequestBody,
    val image: MultipartBody.Part
)
```

When the server team receives and uses this list, it must be able to call and use as follows:

```
dataList[0].text
dataList[0].image
```

I found these ways.

1. Send only one non-file data.
2. Send multiple non-file data. (PartMap)
3. Send only one file data.
4. Send multiple file data. (List<MultipartBody.Part>)

But I couldn't find a way to send a list of data class objects with non-file data and file data.
How do I define a Retrofit service to send a list available on the server side in the way I said it?

Answer (score 0):

To send a list as a RequestBody, you have to convert it to json string before wraping it into a RequestBody (with the extension function toRequestBody()).

Here is a sample :

```
@Multipart
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("/post")
fun addPost(
    @Part dataList: RequestBody,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,
): Call<PostResponse>
```

And the post call. I use Gson to convert the model (the list) into a Json string :

```
fun addPostCall(
    dataList: List<DataItem>,
    image: File,
) {
    myServiceClient.addPost(
        dataList = Gson()
            .toJson(dataList)
            .toRequestBody(),
        file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "file",
            image.name,
            image.asRequestBody((image
                .toURI()
                .toURL()
                .openConnection().contentType ?: image.extension
                .takeIf { extension -> extension.isNotEmpty() }
                ?.let { extension ->
                    MimeTypeMap
                        .getSingleton()
                        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
                })?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
            ),
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Why is the file sent separately from this code?